# App Inventor 2: Invalid Destination Address

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm getting the error when InviteButton.Click is pressed, when trying to send the actual message. Everything else loads up as it should, I am able to select a contact etc.

I've the following block of code:

I'm using contact picker to pick the number:
[image: Contact Picker]

Then I'm trying to call the value stored in the tinyDB and send the message like this:
[image: Call Send Message]

And this is the error i get:
[image: Error]

Basically I'm trying to pick a number from the contact picker, add to the tinyDB and when I press a button it sends the text message....can't figure it out.

Any ideas??

Comment: when do you get this error? at launch? after you choose a contact? after clicking invite? The more information you can give, the more people will be willing and able to help

Comment: Sorry about that, edited

Comment: You are calling the texting component with empty number.Did you some debugging? What about checking the value (contatNumber) before storing into DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some data validation before sending the message, something like this

[image]

By the way, the `if true` statement does not make sense, you can remove it...